# How do I handle server redirects with apache

Tags: apache-http-server

I have a windows 10 pc running Apache with a couple VMs and another windows pc running octoprint. What I want to accomplish is going to `pc1.local/octoprint` points to `http://[pc2ipaddress]:[portnumber]`.

The issue is going to the octoprint ip address redirects to the login page then elsewhere. So, when I type in `pc1.local/octoprint` it changes to `pc1.local/login/...` which clearly doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pc1.local
    #ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Proxy for octoprint
    ProxyPass /octoprint/ http://192.168.x.xxx:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse /octoprint/ http://192.168.x.xxx:5000/
    

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: it sounds like the octoprint application is set to require authentication, and is sending the user to the login page so that they can login. this is common behavior for just about all web applications that are configured to require login. I'd focus on how you can configure the webapp to allow anonymous useage, and then expect that the redirect issue will resolve itself .

Comment: Hmm, but ProxyPassReverse is already supposed to do exactly this, isn't it? Could it be that the webapp uses JavaScript to do the redirects?